# Simulate Eye-tracking by Photoshop filters?

Tags: psychology, visual-design, hci, eye-tracking

I've read some articles about visual perception and that it mostly differs in High-frequency, Mid-frequency and Low-frequency recognition. Whereas [Low-freq is fastest](http://www.perceptionweb.com/abstract.cgi?id=p261047) and seems to be responsible for overall orientation. [Mid-freq is important for letter recognition](http://www.psych.umn.edu/engellab/Downloads/VR98.pdf) and High-freq for all details. See the image below for an idea of it.

[image][image][image][image]

Source: [psy.vanderbilt.edu, also a good article about visual frequencies](http://www.psy.vanderbilt.edu/courses/hon185/SpatialFrequency/SpatialFrequency.html)

Its a very scientific field, but I think it can help us to improve our screen and icon design. I guess you already stumbled upon images like this below, where you still "see" the person although its very "unsharp" (only Low-frequencies aka no details). Actually you can simulate it through a simple Gauss-filter, too.

[image]

source: [http://www.yorku.ca](http://www.yorku.ca/eye/popepix3.htm)

### Okay, complicated introduction followed by a simple question:

**Is there a study, workflow, dedicated photoshop-filter, that can give me the ability to simulate an Eye-tracking situation?**

...to check my layout: grasp the first impression, the idea of visual flow/attention and order of perception.

There is a common workaround for designers: you slightly pinch one eye together and see a blurry overall impression. But having it more precise would be awesome.

I played around a little, but I think its not accurate and still half the way
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. Frequency is one issue - but eye tracking is *all* about eye saccades.

This is a mild oversimplification - hopefully folk won't mind.

Hold your arm out and stick your thumb up. The size of top half of your thumb is roughly the size of the bit of your visual field that sees in 'high res' - the fovea. It takes up less than 1% of the retina area, but uses up about 50% of the visual cortex.

The fact that everything around you seems to be a high quality image is just your mind doing a really great modelling job. We dont 'see' the world, we see very small chunks of it and our brain does a bang up job of producing a nice high-rez simulation for us to work with internally ;-)

The eyes tend to move around in small fast movements called 'saccades' - these movements are what eye tracking rigs track. They are about figuring out where the 'high res' bit of the visual field is pointing - since that's where our visual attention is (which does *not* necessarily mean that what we're looking at is of interest, or what we expect, or that we're reading it, etc. - but this isn't the eye tracking rant so I'll hush...)

In fact there have been fascinating experiments where you have folk in eye tracking rigs looking at pictures. When their focus moves from one point to another - during the saccadic movement - you can change the bit of the picture that they were looking at and people tend not to notice anything amiss (see http://www.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/hollingworth/documents/hendholl_pp03.pdf for example).

So applying visual filters across the whole image aren't going to help you figure out where eyes are likely to go. Most of the processing happens where the eye already is ;-)

Especially since static images miss major cues that cause saccades like movement (there are parts of the eye that are sensitive to movement across the visual field and these are often cues for saccades - which is why those ever-rotating things are a crap idea since they involuntarily cause the people looking at the page to look at the moving thing...).

Comment: Nice Answer !..

Comment: May be I musunderstood the idea of heatmaps, but aren't they for testing if a user sees some (for me) important infos? As you pointed out the image is in your head, but you just scan a webpage rapidely in order to find your goal (button/text/link) as fast as possible. the rest are just some blurry blocks for your mind. For reading and processing consciously you need to recognise the text aka have a eye movement and some time there.

Comment: If I as a shop owner want to be sure, that you as customer sees my trusted shop sign, I could use an eye-tracking test, don't I? And may be some modifications in position can help "the eyes" to recognise my certificate more easily. The  movements of your eye (and even the small saccades) are influenced by the layout of the page, which is influenced by low frequencies heavily (because low freq are fastest to be processed in your biological eye).

Comment: So, low freq are steering your eye through the page (like strong b/w of hue contrasts). This is why Im looking for a hint, tool or workaround to get an idea where the (unconscious) attention of users are likely to go.

Comment: That focus experiment reminds me of this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voAntzB7EwE

Comment: You know this one? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJG698U2Mvo

Comment: Heat maps is really just _one of the analyses_ you can get from an e.t. study.  The e.t. software just logs every gaze rapidly. For the logo example, you could use an "Area of interest" analysis instead. Define various areas you would like to know if the user has focused on.  After all recordings you can fragment your audience by gender or age or anything you want (custom questions you add to your test-) and find out who has focused on this area.  This is really advanced research, because even if they have focused on it, you don't know if they noticed it - and you don't know if they liked it.

Comment: @FrankL All eye tracking heat maps are is a view of how much total time was spent "focussed" on areas. They're often aggregates from multiple users. They don't let you know if somebody comprehended what they were looking at, or whether the gaze was conscious or unconscious. E.g. I've seen eye tracking studies that showed many people fixated on an area, but their behaviour and follow up questions showed nobody had actually read the text (it was in a banner blindness spot). This sort of thing is why I rank eye tracking as one of the least useful general user testing tools ;)

Comment: @FrankL The point I was trying to make was that those papers aren't (as far as I can see) talking about low frequencies steering the eye in the way that eye tracking studies are normally used. They're talking about figuring out the model for how different frequencies are integrated. The first is talking about its effect on slow-pursuit eye movements - which are different from the fast "unconscious" saccades that eye tracking studies normally focus on (I don't have access to the full paper so may be missing something).

Comment: @FrankL The the second is comparing low/medium/high frequencies so they are basically talking about stuff that's coming via the fovea and, by definition, what the eye has already looked at. So no input on eye tracking behaviour their either. I'm sure that frequency will have an effect - but it's going to be a complex feedback driven one based on the model generated via the processing in the visual cortex.

Comment: @FrankL Finally, we know from observing eye tracking results, that our attention is being driven by much higher-level abstractions (e.g. our tendency to pay attention to faces, the F-pattern in left-right-top-bottom reading cultures, etc.) unrelated to the frequency info in the image.

Comment: adrianh and @Jørn E. Angeltveit thanks a lot for your input. It actually helped me to get a better understanding of the pro&cons of eye-tracking. Its hard to choose one as the answer as both helped me. I will set adrianh's, because of more written letters  8-)

Comment: This is obviously a bit fussy but eye tracking isn't really about saccades, it's about fixations. Your average usability lab eye tracker does not have a temporal resolution sufficient to actually measure saccades, it just records where the gaze is “staying” for a longer time and assumes that what's in between is a saccade.

Comment: Heat maps in particular only reflect fixations and provide no insight on the path through the page or the saccades themselves.

Comment: Also, the issue is still somewhat debated but it's not clear we are seeing anything at all during saccades. The destination of the saccade is fixed before the movement starts and cannot be altered during the saccade itself (it's said to be stereotyped and ballistic) and that's what makes the experiment you describe possible. The focus of visual attention is therefore “decided” beforehand based at least in part on peripheral vision so that analyses of the whole image seem very relevant to guess what the gaze path is likely to be.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans - Yup. Completely right. As I said "mild oversimplification" ;-) And obviously some cues for gaze path must be coming from the peripheral vision - motion across the visual field being the most obvious example. But I think that things like the F-pattern show that there's a lot of higher-level drivers for gaze path too. Visual frequency is, I think, unlikely to be a useful cue by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [Feng-GUI.com](http://www.feng-gui.com) tries to create a heatmap based on AI.

The reliability has been discussed in other questions:

- [Has anyone got experience of Feng GUI and been able to test it against real users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/26532/95)

[image]

Comment: I did a small experiment with FengGui. See thread there.

Comment: ...and "there" is "[here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/29199/95)" ;-)